# Проверьте мой код пожалуйста и скажите как сделать так

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проверьте мой код пожалуйста и скажите как сделать так чтобы все имена и адреса почт записывались в файл на моем рабочем столе(Base.pickle) и при функции удаления из программы(которая прописана в программе) ,они удалялись из этого файла ,а когда просмотр инфы подгружалось из этого файла .

```
import pickle


def create_human(name, email):
    humans = {}
    humans[name] = email
    f = open('Base.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(humans, f)
    f.close()


def print_email(name):
    print(humans[name])


def delete_user(name):
    del human[name]


def foo(name):
    if name in human:
        print('Такой человек есть.')


print('''Вы вошли в Адресную книгу .Для выбора функции нажмите соответствующую клавишу.
    1)Для просмотра информации о человеке.
    2)Для добавления нового человека.
    3)Для изменения информации о человеке.
    4)Для удаления человека.
    5)Для поиска человека.
''')
run = int(input('Выберите функцию:'))

if run == 1:
    print('Чтобы посмотреть информацию о пользователе напишите его Фамилию и Имя (с большой буквы). ')
    name = input('Ввод:')
    print_email(name)

elif run == 2:
    print('Чтобы добавить нового человека запишите сначала его имя и фамилию,а потом адрес эл.почты.')
    name = input('Введите ФИ:')
    email = input('Введите адрес эл.почты:')
    create_human(name, email)

elif run == 3:
    print('Чтобы изменить адрес эл.почты ,просто напишите ФИ пользователя и новый адрес.')
    name = input('Введите имя:')
    email = input('Введите новый адрес эл.почты:')
    create_human(name, email)

elif run == 4:
    print('Чтобы удалить человека введите его имя.')
    name = input('Введите имя:')
    delete_user(name)

elif run == 5:
    print('Чтобы проверить если ли человек в базе ,введите его имя.')
    name = input('Введите имя:')
    foo(name)

else:
    print('Функции под таким номером не существует!')
```

Comment: Зависит от того, какая именно у вас программа, вообще лучше начать отсюда:  https://python-scripts.com/database. Там всё есть, выберите для себя подходящий путь и задавайте вопросы уже по реализации конкретно, или если не знаете какой путь выбрать - более подробно опишите что из себя представляет ваша программа, а не этот кусочек кода.
Как видите ваш вопрос словил "минус" и это из-за того, что вопросы на таких форумах принято задавать максимально чётко и развёрнуто, если вы совсем не знаете что делать и у вас не получается "нагуглить", то так и пишите и задавайте вопрос, повторюсь, чётко

Answer (score 0):

Для создания словаря Вы используете функцию dump.

Соответственно для работы со словарем необходимо использовать функцию load.

```
def print_email(name):
    f = open('Base.pickle', 'rb')
    humans[name] = pickle.load(f)
    print(humans[name])
```